Nuxt 3: useRoute() returning wrong value for 'page' parameter
I'm using Nuxt version 3.11.2 with Nitro 2.9.6. I have a search results page which returns data from the API:

I have a computed property called params which extend useRoute().params like so:
const route = useRoute()
const params = computed<Record<string, any>>(() => {
  let params = route.params
  if (params.inventory) {
    const [inventoryName, inventoryId] = params.inventory.toString().split(';')
    params = useAssignIn({ inventory_id: inventoryId, item_name: inventoryName }, params)
  }
  if (params.city) {
    const [cityName, cityId] = params.city.toString().split(';')
    params = useAssignIn({ city_id: cityId, city_name: unslugify(cityName) }, params)
  }
  return params
})

When I perform a search from the home page, the search results page parses the 'page' parameter with a wrong value - one time it is "1" and the other time "2". Both useRoute().params.page and params.page produce the same result: one time it is "1" and the other "2" (while it should be "1" by default). The URL looks like this:
http://localhost:3000/en/cars/search/;0/;0/1/30
As you can see, the value of the 'page' parameter in the URL is "1", but it sometimes produces "2". Is this a Nuxt 3 bug?
